# how to build outlook plug in

Tags: c#, vsto

i want to make plug in for outlook.i build an application in which i am creating contact,appointment n tasks.i want to see these contact,appointment n task in outlook and if i create any contact in outlook .i want to see outlook  contact in application contacts...  i had read many article but till now  i don,t get any idea.....

plz reply how can i do this

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft provides VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) framework to write addins for Office applications. VSTO 2010 is available for download. Once installed, you can use the Wizard in Visual Studio to create an addin.

Here's the Download Link: [VSTO 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128768.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you can use vsto outlook template,

the link below shows u some great outlook plug in development samples

[click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd162450.aspx)
and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897406.aspx)
and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/dd253199.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

NetOffice so far is the best framework for this.
I've done a few POCs with VSTO, COM Add-Ins and NetOffice, overall the latter gives way more convenience in developing.

Still to find if I hit a brick wall when doing something non-trivial and will have to resort to COM Add-In.

http://netoffice.codeplex.com/